# Blockchain platform in C

Tags: blockchain, corda

I am trying to understand available blockchain frameworks, I have two questions:

Is there any permissible blockchain platform supporting c/c++, I have looked at Hyperledger and Corda, they seem to be build on go and java?

Another question I have is, is there any true(where I can see and study the source code) open source blockchain platform(apart from bitcoins), Hyperledger and Corda seem to release only binaries

Answer (score 1):

There are many implementations of Blockchain like [Ethereum](https://github.com/ethereum/), Eris, Sidechain... I suggest you to study Ethereum.

On the other hand, probably they are not build on c/c ++, but Ethereum has a client developed on C++ ([cpp-ethereum - Ethereum C++ client](https://github.com/ethereum/cpp-ethereum))

Comment: Thanks, I think ethereum is not permissive - One can not control as who participates in chain, Multichain seems to be based on c/c++ and allows private blockchain creation

Answer (score 0):

Corda is written in Kotlin, but applications on Corda (CorDapps) can be written in any JVM language.

Corda is open-source under Apache 2.0. The source code is here: https://github.com/corda/corda.